# No segments* file found in MMapDirectory

Tags: java, lucene, lucene.net, spell-checking

I would like to do autocorrection, but when I run code getting into error, I noticed something was wrong with both `DictionaryReader` and `LuceneDictionary`, but when I go running it with `Plaintextdictionary` it works fine. I can't figure out what's wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Output Error:

> org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file
>   found in
>   MMapDirectory@C:...
>   lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@1cd072a9:
>   files: []     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:675)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:64)
>     at CreateSpellCheckerIndex.main(test.java:42)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.spell.LuceneDictionary;
import org.apache.lucene.search.spell.PlainTextDictionary;
import org.apache.lucene.search.spell.SpellChecker;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;


public class CreateSpellCheckerIndex {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String indexDir = "/Index";
    String SpellCheckDir = "/Data";
    String indexField = "contains";
    String words="Data/words.txt";
    //Creating SpellCheck Index
    System.out.println("Now build SpellChecker index...");
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(SpellCheckDir));
    Directory dir2=FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexDir));

    SpellChecker spell = new SpellChecker(dir);     
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(null);
    IndexReader r=DirectoryReader.open(dir2);

    try
    {
      LuceneDictionary dict = new LuceneDictionary(r,indexField);
      spell.indexDictionary(dict,config,true);
    }finally{
       r.close();
    }
    //Add words to SpellChecker Index
    //IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(null);
    //spell.indexDictionary(new PlainTextDictionary(Paths.get(words)),config,false);  
    dir2.close();   
    dir.close();
    spell.close();
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("  took " + (endTime-startTime) + " milliseconds");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any issue with ur code and also it works fine for me. Could u make sure u r using the latest version of lucene.